# Import/Export to VCard format programmatically using android OS 2.0 API level 5

Tags: android

The Android 2.0 SDK has a import/export option to export or import contacts in VCard format.

Is there any API to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Try such code for export to VCard:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
AssetFileDescriptor fd = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
if (0 < fis.read(buf))
{
   String vCard = new String(buf);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the lookupKey in the first line of your code??