# How can i export contacts to .vcf file

Tags: android, export, contacts

i want to export the contacts in my device to .Vcf file, can any one help me who can i do so? since all what i get when i search in google is how to export using the contacts menu not in code. 
thanks in advance for helping

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8701727/1321873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try belowpost for export contacts in android phone:

[Import/Export to VCard format programmatically using android OS 2.0 API level 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721249/import-export-to-vcard-format-programmatically-using-android-os-2-0-api-level-5)

[Extract contact list in vcf format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701727/extract-contact-list-in-vcf-format)

Thanks!

Comment: @Denish how can i import the contacts again from the .vcf file i get?

Comment: try below link for vcard source code on google code http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/downloads/list